# Cannot convert from void to PVector in Processing

Tags: processing

I'm learning processing and am trying generate fractals using Pascal's triangle. This requires arrays of `PVectors`. I have run into an issue that I don't understand—I'm getting `cannot convert from void to PVector`

This is an excerpt, not every variable is defined in the excerpt, but I figure the issue is probably something such that I won't need to reveal more code than this—more code shown might just obfuscate the problem.

```java
arrayCopy(points,old_points);
points = new PVector[int(pow(2, j))];
if (j == 1)
{
  points[0] = new PVector(0,0);
}
if (j == 2)
{
  points[0] = new PVector(1,0);
  points[1] = new PVector(-1,0);
}
else
{
  //j will be 3 for the THIRD term in the series
  int number_of_terms_to_fill = int(pow(j - 1, 2));
  int[] pasc = PascalTriangle(j - 1);
  float real = findReal(pasc, x, y, number_of_terms_to_fill);
  float imagi = findImagi(pasc, x, y, number_of_terms_to_fill);
  PVector v = new PVector(real, imagi);
  for (int k = 0; k < number_of_terms_to_fill; k = k + 2)
  {
    points[k] = old_points[k].add(v); //!!***PROBLEM LINE***!!!
    points[k+1] = old_points[k].sub(v); 
  }
}
```

My other functions, such as `findReal` and `findImagi`, I believe are correct. The addition on the problem line should be an addition between two `PVectors`—a legal operation. Instead something is void? Perhaps `arrayCopy` isn't a deep copy like I'd want?

Not sure what is going on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method .add() does not return a PVector (it returns nothing, thus void) so you can't do

```
points[k] = old_points[k].add(v);
```

I suppose what you are trying to do is add v to old_points[k] and pass it to points[k] which will not work like that... You have to do it like this:

```
old_points[k].add(v);
points[k] = old_points[k];
old_points[k].sub(v);
points[k+1] = old_points[k];
```

In order for what you wrote to be valid, the add function should have been like this:

```
PVector add(PVector v) {
  this.x += v.x;
  this.y += v.y;
  this.z += v.z;
  return this;
}
```

Instead it looks sort of like this:

```
void add(PVector v) {
  this.x += v.x;
  this.y += v.y;
  this.z += v.z;
}
```

Edit: After Ryan's comment below, I provide here another way, using the static .add() method which does return a PVector...

```
points[k] = PVector.add(old_points[k],v);
points[k+1] = PVector.sub(old_points[k],v);
```

Comment: Actually, [the reference](http://processing.org/reference/PVector_add_.html) says `Returns void or PVector`

Comment: I see. The add and subtract operations are mean to be used standalone. Fair enough. Thanks!

Comment: @RyanCarlson edited, @ PinkElephantsOnParade you are welcome!